# How do I get the client IP of a Tornado web socket request?

Tags: python, websocket, ip, tornado

How do I get the client IP of a Tornado **websocket** request?

I have a RequestHandler object for incoming connection()s. How can I find the IP of the client who has just connected?

```
def open(self):
        ChatSocketHandler.clients.add(self)
        i2c.write_byte_data(0x70, 0x00, 0xa5)
        IR_on = True
        print "Connection initiated"
        ChatSocketHandler.send_updates("IR on")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like normal `RequestHandler` instances, `WebsocketHandler` instances  have a [`HTTPServerRequest`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httputil.html?highlight=remote_ip#tornado.httputil.HTTPServerRequest) object set to the `request` attribute of the `Handler`. You can use the [`HTTPServerRequest.remote_ip`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httputil.html?highlight=remote_ip#tornado.httputil.HTTPServerRequest.remote_ip) attribute to get the IP of the remote connection. For example:

```
class EchoWebSocket(websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def initialize(self):
        self._closed = False

    def open(self):
        print(type(self.request))
        print(self.request)
        print(self.request.remote_ip)
```

Output when a request is received:

```
<class 'tornado.httputil.HTTPServerRequest'>
HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='localhost:8888', method='GET', uri='/ws', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='::1', headers={'Connection': 'Upgrade', 'Upgrade': 'websocket', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Sec-Websocket-Version': '13', 'Host': 'localhost:8888', 'Sec-Websocket-Key': 'oAJpF4f4kp26b2KRjYmRGw=='})
::1
```

Comment: when I connect from external of my network, i.e. 3g it shows the ip of my modem instead, how could i show the true originating ip please

Comment: @Ossama The router is acting like a reverse proxy in this scenario - the client is connecting to your Public IP (which is your router) and the router is forwarding the request on to your local IP (`192.168.x.x` for example). If the router isn't including the real client IP in the headers its passing to `tornado`, it may not be possible for you to get the real client IP. You could try using the [`xheaders` option](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httputil.html?highlight=remote_ip#tornado.httputil.HTTPServerRequest.remote_ip) and see if your router includes `X-Real-IP`/`X-Forwarded-For`.

Comment: how can i get this? my header is as follow,

Comment: HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='192.168.0.6:8888', method='GET', uri='/ws', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='192.168.0.3', headers={'Origin': 'http://192.168.0.6', 'Upgrade': 'websocket', 'Sec-Websocket-Extensions': 'x-webkit-deflate-frame', 'Sec-Websocket-Version': '13', 'Connection': 'Upgrade', 'Sec-Websocket-Key': 'klB25dpHtCvRri6UXqKxEw==', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_0_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12A405 Safari/600.1.4', 'Host': '192.168.0.6:8888', 'Pragma': 'no-cache', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'})